# matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch is not being called after accepting Invite

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, game-center, gamekit

I am making a real time Game Center game, with GameKit as a new programmer, however I have run into a few road blocks.

I am able to properly initialize the local player, present the matchmaking viewController, and receive and accept invites, however, even after I accept the invite  `matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch` is not called and no match is returned to me. There is a high likelihood that I did not accept the invitation correct, but according to apples developer forums I have. If someone could review this code and let me know how to have that method be called that'd be great!

```
let request = GKMatchRequest()

class SecondScreenViewController : UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKLocalPlayerListener {

    let button = UIButton()
    let softRed = UIColor(red: 1, green: 61 / 255, blue: 61 / 255, alpha: 1)
    let softblue = UIColor(red: 38 / 255, green: 149 / 255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    let TestMatchMaker = GKMatchmaker()
    let TestMatch = GKMatch()
    var TestViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    
    var player = GKLocalPlayer.local

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        player.register(self)
        setupButton()
        SetupRequest()
        view.backgroundColor = softblue
        
       
    }

    func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("cancelled")
    }
    
    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription + "THIS IS AN ERROR FROM THE VIEWCONTROLLER")
    }
    
    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {
        print("Found Match Successfully")
        let TestMatch = match
        print(TestMatch)
    }
    
    
    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {
        print(invite)
        print("Aceppted Invite")
        
        TestViewController?.setHostedPlayer(player, didConnect: true)
        
        
        
    }
    
    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didRequestMatchWithRecipients recipientPlayers: [GKPlayer]) {
        print("Requested Match")
    }
    
    func SetupRequest() {
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 2
        request.inviteMessage = "test Invite"
    }

    
    func setupButton() {
         button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
         button.setTitleColor(softblue, for: .normal)
         button.setTitle("MatchMake", for: .normal)
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
         
         view.addSubview(button)
         setupButtonConstraints()
     }
     
     func setupButtonConstraints() {
         button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
         button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
         button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
         button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
         
     }
     
     @objc func ButtonTapped() {
        
        present(TestViewController!, animated: true, completion: {
            self.TestViewController!.delegate = self})
        TestViewController?.matchmakerDelegate = self
        
        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that might be causing it is when you set the matchmaker delegate. Here is the code I am using to invite players and it is working properly:

```
func invitePlayers(){
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = 2
    request.maxPlayers = 4
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
    let vc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    vc?.matchmakerDelegate = self
    self.present(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

notice that the matchmakerDelegate is set before the ViewController is presented.